# How do you change from portrait to landscape in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, aspect-ratio, cropping

I have a picture that I shot in landscape (4x6 ratio) that I want to crop to portrait (5x7 ratio). I see how I can do a 5x7 landscape or a 4x6 portrait, but not a 5x7 portrait.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in crop mode in development module, grab tool before Aspect text, click on the picture and draw in desired orientation.
[image]

This method is slightly different from the others and should work every time without problems.

Comment: By the way, that was delicious apple pie ;)

Answer (score 23):

While you can drag corner handles and hope to get it right, the easiest way is to **press the X key on the keyboard**.

Comment: This is the best answer. It directly does what's requested, rather than having to drag a crop corner until orientation changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you drag the cropping handles far enough the aspect should automtically flip between landscape and portrait while retaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for me. It does if I keep the aspect ratio at 4x6, but not when I change it to 5x7.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just drag a corner handle over the top edge, and the orientation will change. It should be noted that Lightroom will not change the orientation if the crop box is too large to fit in a particular orientation. It is best to shrink the crop box small, reorient, then resize and pan as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out! You have to be in Library mode; there is a little curved arrow below each pic, that's what you use to rotate the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Under the menu "settings" click on "rotate crop aspect" which is found near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To flip the entire photo, not merely rotate the crop:

1. Develop mode > Photo (4th in the upper menu bar)
2. > Rotate Left (CCW) or Rotate Right (CW)

Either will flip the entire image.